# RegEx for string in typescript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I am working in angular 8 and I have strings with pattern like "Cho Wan (Wan_Cho@xyz.com - THV)". I want to write a regular expression that splits this string into an array like below:

```
arr[0]= "Ilsa"

arr[1]= "Cho"

arr[2]= "Cho_Ilsa@xyz.com"

arr[3] = "TTT"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What should `"Jean-Claude Van Damme (jean_claude_van_damme@xyz.com - THV)"` split into?

Comment: Basically middle name and last name can be combined into one string. And with the email there is hyphen and department name like in the example above. This is the part of pattern.

Comment: @Ahsan How do you determine what is a first-name/middle-name/last-name? Some people have two first names, some have two last names. On what criteria do you differentiate that? (Not to mention that in many Asian countries, the family name comes first.)

Comment: In the example above for Cho Wan, Cho is last name and Wan is first name. And if there is a string like Cho Wan Riz, first name is Riz and last name will be Cho Wan

Comment: @Ivar also, Hungary uses the Familyname Firstname pattern. Something I learned very recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my prediction: Whatever complicated regex you come up with *someone's input will break it*! There has to be a better way to get these details - some system generates this string - go to the source!

That said, this is a rather naive regex which at least passes the 3 test cases that have been discussed:

```
/([\w-]+) ([\w\s]+) \((.+@.+?) - ([\w\s-]+)\)/
```

Live example:

```js
var regex = /([\w-]+) ([\w\s]+) \((.+@.+?) - ([\w\s-]+)\)/

var cho = regex.exec("Cho Wan (Wan_Cho@xyz.com - THV)");
console.log(`cho[1]: ${cho[1]}
cho[2]: ${cho[2]}
cho[3]: ${cho[3]}
cho[4]: ${cho[4]}`);

var cho2 = regex.exec("Cho Wan Riz (Riz_WanCho@xyz.com - Default - THV)");
console.log(`cho2[1]: ${cho2[1]}
cho2[2]: ${cho2[2]}
cho2[3]: ${cho2[3]}
cho2[4]: ${cho2[4]}`);

var jcvd = regex.exec("Jean-Claude Van Damme (jean_claude_van_damme@xyz.com - THV)");
console.log(`jcvd[1]: ${jcvd[1]}
jcvd[2]: ${jcvd[2]}
jcvd[3]: ${jcvd[3]}
jcvd[4]: ${jcvd[4]}`);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, if I have something like "Cho Wan Riz (Riz_WanCho@xyz.com - Default - THV)". It does not parse this correctly. I want an array like: arr[0] = Riz, arr[1] = WanCho, arr[2] = Riz_WanCho@xyz.com, arr[3] = Default-THV

Comment: @Ahsan see update. But you've really hit on my first point that there will be _loads_ of edge cases and you're unlikely to fix them all. Or, if you do, the regex will be so complicated as to be useless in the long run.